# ffmpeg How to end a specific process?

Tags: ffmpeg

If I have multiple ffmpeg running in the background, for example:

process 1

```
ffmpeg -re -i "https://mnmedias.api.telequebec.tv/m3u8/29880.m3u8" -filter_complex "null" -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -f flv ./videos/cut-videos/standard/happens.mp4
```

process 2

```
ffmpeg -re -i "https://mnmedias.api.telequebec.tv/m3u8/29880.m3u8" -filter_complex "null" -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -f flv ./videos/cut-videos/standard/happens2.mp4
```

process 3

```
ffmpeg -re -i "https://mnmedias.api.telequebec.tv/m3u8/29880.m3u8" -filter_complex "null" -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -f flv ./videos/cut-videos/standard/happens3.mp4
```

How Can I end process 3 specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pgrep` alone to get the PID:

```
pgrep -f happens3.mp4
```

Example with `kill`:

```
kill "$(pgrep -f happens3.mp4)"
```

Comment: This is it! thank you so much lordNeckBeard and for your help before as well!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ps -ef | grep happens3.mp4 | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

This should give you the PID to that exact process.

For this example, let's say your PID is 1234.

To kill it, run the following

```
kill 1234
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved my issue, do you know of a way to retrieve what is outputted onto a Nodejs app? i am trying to create a command to do it on my app

Comment: Will the output also include the `grep` process?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard no the output for the solution just gives two numbers 15832
15845 The first of which is the PID, I just want to retrieve this number on my app. I have a package that basically runs terminal commands on my app so I was thinking I would use this solution and somehow find a way to get the PID number outputted back on to my app

Comment: @Ricky The 2nd number is likely from `grep`.