# How to stop ffmpeg live stream to youtube over cron?

Tags: python, web-services, ffmpeg

I want to stream a video to youtube,

But don't know what to do to stop that live stream, like I want to stop in case wrong video gets streamed.

Like if i do a `python subprocess` or `via cron` not attached to the output, How can I stop the streaming and probably kill `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux & macOS you can use:

```
kill $(pgrep ffmpeg)
```

Note that this will stop **all** `ffmpeg` instances. If you want to be more discriminate see [ffmpeg How to end a specific process?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48712478/), or look into creating a PID file for each process.

Comment: Thanks! nice command. If may ask, I am planning to use it on a web app, Is it right? where multiple people may  stream this way on a web app. Or is there a better alternative to do this kind of a thing.

Comment: @code0x00 "Web app" is a really generic term. I don't know any details so I don't know if there is a better alternative.